# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 when trying to get data from Sybase database using odbc

Tags: php, codeigniter, odbc, sybase

I'm setting up a former PHP project on the CodeIgniter framework and i want to get some data from a SYBASE database using ODBC.

It works fine when it isn't a lot of data but when i need to get massive data it just gives me a HTTP ERROR 500.

On my former project, where i dont use CI, i didn't get this error but i got some time_limit_error which i fixed by extending 'max_execution_time';

I have tried this on CI but it is pointless and the error i get from CI isn't specific cause it just says 'HTTP ERROR 500';

The connection is properly made, since it works when i don't need massive data, but i'm not using the CI standards for it because i was having problems  with that too.

Does anyone knows why i get this error and why can i fix it?

I got this error on apache log :

```
[Fri Apr 12 14:49:03.573513 2019] [php7:error] [pid 11768:tid 1964] [client ::1:55425] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35767312 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\CodeIgniter\\system\\core\\Output.php on line 198, referer: http://localhost/CodeIgniter/Samsic/provisoes 
[Fri Apr 12 14:49:03.574982 2019] [php7:error] [pid 11768:tid 1964] [client::1:55425] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35770368 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost/CodeIgniter/Samsic/provisoes
```

print page :

```
> <?php ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");  ?> <!DOCTYPE html> <html>
> <head>    <title></title>     <style>     body{       font-size: 0.9em;   }
>   .container{         width: 100%;        height: 100%;   }
> 
>   @media print {      @page { margin: 20px; }         body { margin: 1.6cm; }     }
>   table, th, td {         border: 1px solid black;    </style> </head> <body
> onload="window.print()">  <?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>   <?=
> $resultado; ?>
> 
> </body> </html>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pagamentos extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Pagamentos_model', '', TRUE);
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['form'] = 'Pagamentosform';
        $this->load->view('norm',$data);

        }
    public function content(){
        $ano = addslashes($this->input->post('anop'));
        $session_data = array('anop' => $ano);
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        $codigo = addslashes($this->session->codigo);
        $resultado=$this->Pagamentos_model->read($codigo,$ano);
        $data['form'] = 'Pagamentosform';
        $data['res'] = 'Pagamentoscontent';
        $data['resultado'] = $resultado;
        $this->load->view('norm',$data);


    }

    public function imprimir(){
        $ano =  addslashes($this->session->anop);
        $codigo = addslashes($this->session->codigo);
        $resultado = $this->Pagamentos_model->imprimir($ano,$codigo);
        $data['resultado'] = $resultado;
        $this->load->view('imprimirTemplate',$data);


    }

    public function grafico(){
        $data['form'] = 'Pagamentosform';
        $data['res'] = 'grafico';
        $codigo = addslashes($this->session->codigo);
        $ano = addslashes($this->session->anop);
        $grafico = $this->Pagamentos_model->grafico($ano,$codigo);
        $data['data'] = $grafico;
        $this->load->view('norm',$data);


    }   

}
```

Model function imprimir:

```
public function imprimir($ano,$codigo){
        require(APPPATH.'libraries/odbc_conn.php');
        $query = odbc_exec($db, 'Select * from GP_Vw_Valores_Pagos where Ano='.$ano.' and Codigo='.$codigo.' order by CD');
        $row=odbc_fetch_array($query);
        $output= '<h1 style="text-align: center;"> Pagamentos'.$ano.' </h1>  <table class="table" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom:40px; margin-top: 15px; ">
      <thead>
        <tr style="font-size: 1em;margin-bottom: 15px;text-align: center;">
          <th scope="col">CD</th>
          <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
          <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
          <th scope="col">Janeiro</th>
          <th scope="col">Fevereiro</th>
          <th scope="col">Março</th>
          <th scope="col">Abril</th>
          <th scope="col">Maio</th>
          <th scope="col">Junho</th>
          <th scope="col">Julho</th>
          <th scope="col">Agosto</th>
          <th scope="col">Setembro</th>
          <th scope="col">Outubro</th>
          <th scope="col">Novembro</th>
          <th scope="col">Dezembro</th>

        </tr> 
        </thead>';

        while($row){
            $output .= '<tr style="text-align: center;">
        <td>' .$row["CD"].'</td>
          <td>'.iconv("CP850", "UTF-8", $row['Descricao']).'</td>
          <td>VI</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl01'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl02'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl03'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl04'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl05'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl06'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl07'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl08'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl09'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl10'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl11'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Vl12'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
               </tr>
               <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>QT</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt01'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt02'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt03'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt04'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt05'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt06'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt07'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt08'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt09'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt10'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt11'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
          <td>' .number_format($row['Qt12'] , 2, '.', '').'</td>
               </tr>  ';
        }

        return $output;


    }
```

Comment: Look for apache/nginx error logs

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: You have to look on apache/nginx installation folder. There is a file called "error_logs" or something like that

Comment: ok i got this on the logs

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35767312 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\CodeIgniter\\system\\core\\Output.php on line 198, referer: http://localhost/CodeIgniter/Samsic/provisoes
[Fri Apr 12 14:49:03.574982 2019] [php7:error] [pid 11768:tid 1964] [client ::1:55425] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35770368 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: h

Comment: Please, edit your question to add the error log.

Comment: i have done that

Comment: Add your `Pagamentos_model->imprimir`

Comment: did u notice something?

Comment: @MacosSilva see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

OK, your are getting this error of memory because you are concatenating the whole table into a string variable inside and endless loop and try to output this.

DO NOT DO THAT ON MODEL.

From your model you should return the values to use on view directly building your view.

You have a lot of fix in this code:

- Do not concatenate to build your layout, it can became HUGE and eventually will run out of memory.
- Your HTML is broken (no `</table>`, for instance)
- Your loop seems to be running forever `while($row)` <- probably this is causing the error, you are not changing $row anywhere, I think it should be `while($row=odbc_fetch_row($query))`.
- I don't know your system, but you could try CodeIgniter way to connect on ODBC: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html
- `addslashes` is unsafe, you should be using `prepared statement` instead: http://www.securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/addslashes-bypass-sql-injection.html

### First try

Your probable running out of memory, as you said you're loading  a lot of data.

Try to find a best value for your needs

```php
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
```

You need to run this before loading the data, or you could change php settings to be system-wide.

Comment: is that the maximum memory i can get? im getting another memory exhausted problem and i've already did what u said

Comment: The memory is limited to how much you have on your server. But where didi you configure the memory_limit: on that specific page? System-wide (on php.ini)? where do you are getting another error?

Comment: Im getting the error on a page that i want to print with "window.load", im configuring the memory limit on the beggining of that page

Comment: `<?php ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
 body{
  font-size: 0.9em;
 }
 .container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 @media print {
  @page { margin: 20px; }
  body { margin: 1.6cm; }
 }
 table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
 </style>
</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
 <?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
 <?= $resultado; ?>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: should i do it like that or u want me to edit the post and put it there? im new here sorry

Comment: thats the page that will be printed after receiving the data